# How to initialize state in react-native-day-picker?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to apply react-native-calendar.
My code is

```
import React from 'react';
import {Calendar} from 'react-native-day-picker';
...
 const MyCalendar = () => (
 var from = new Date();
 from.setDate(from.getDate() - 16);
 var to = new Date();
 var startDate = new Date();
 startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
<View style={styles.container}>
            <Calendar
                monthsCount={24}
                startFormMonday={true}
                startDate={startDate}
                selectFrom={from}
                selectTo={to}
                width={350}
                onSelectionChange={(current, previous) => {
                    console.log(current, previous);
                }}
            />
        </View>;
);
export default MyCalendar;
```

Then I got Syntax Error. but I don't prefer style as shown due to some requirement of our Project manager:

```
class XXX extends XXXX {
constructor(...) {
}
render() { ...}
}
```

My problem is how can I initialize the values such as from, to, startDate.
So How should I fix this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use block body { } if we have multiple statements for arrow functions.

Refer to [Function body description of arrow functions in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

> In a **concise body**, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. In a **block body**, you must use an explicit return
>   statement.

Therefore you need to return the View component which is last statement of your MyCalendar.

And that why I remove the { } for onSelectionChange of Calendar component because we can use concise body for one line statement.

---

Some extra repairs.

For those variables we never reassign value, we should use **const**.

Refer to [Enforce boolean attributes notation in JSX (jsx-boolean-value)](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-boolean-value.md) of eslint-plugin-react rules,

> When using a boolean attribute in JSX, you can set the attribute value
>   to true or omit the value. This rule will enforce one or the other to
>   keep consistency in your code.

That why I removed the true value for startFormMonday in Calendar.

Code after repaired as following,

```
const MyCalendar = () => {
  const from = new Date();
  from.setDate(from.getDate() - 16);
  const to = new Date();
  let startDate = new Date();
  startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Calendar
        monthsCount={24}
        startFormMonday
        startDate={startDate}
        selectFrom={from}
        selectTo={to}
        width={350}
        onSelectionChange={(current, previous) => console.log(current, previous)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am using [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor and using [eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) as my styleguide. They help alot in syntax error detection.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
I fixed them as your recommend.
Btw are you familiar of date-picker plugin?
If so, could you help me want to implement it under requirement?
The period of Date is from today to 365 days.
The above code shows about 2 years ranges of Date.
I updated monthCount={12}
But still the same.
I mean if today is 8/23/2016, shows 8/1/2016 ~ 8/1/2017
I would be grateful if you help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I think u can install moment package and refer to this link
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ to get the date of 365 days from now or even the date of 1 year subtract 1 day. After you get the calculated date then put it as value of selectTo?

Answer (score 1):

```
- </View>; you can't have semicolon after tags
- You have to write views in return(...)
- Now you can call myCalender from class

 const MyCalendar = function () {
        var from = new Date();
     from.setDate(from.getDate() - 16);
     var to = new Date();
     var startDate = new Date();
     startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
                <Calendar
                    monthsCount={24}
                    startFormMonday={true}
                    startDate={startDate}
                    selectFrom={from}
                    selectTo={to}
                    width={350}
                    onSelectionChange={(current, previous) => {
                        console.log(current, previous);
                    }}
                />
            </View>
    );
    };
```